# How can I differ between elements that have some same and some different classes in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So I have two elements that I am trying to describe in selenium with classes:
`element1` has `class1` and `class2`, and `element2` has `class1`, `class2`, `class3`. I describe element1 like this:

`element1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(.class1.class2)[0]`

But when my script runs, element1 somehow includes element2. How can I desribe these elements so that they would differ? (xpath is not applicable because these are calendar cells and I need to reach all of them without writing a description for each of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not(.class3)` to locate an element without that class

```
element1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.class1.class2:not(.class3)')[0]
```